# Xcode : Some image assets appear Unassigned after git clone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git

As usual I've commited my `Xcode` project with `Xcode Source Control` interface. Then, when I clone the project, for a unknown reason, some images from the `Assets.xcassets` folder appear with a warning showing **`Unassigned`**. See attached screenshot :

[image: Image unassigned]

If I drag the `Unassigned` image to `1x`, the warning disappear. But I have to do this with each concerned image, and each time I clone the project.

What is weird is that the image get correctly commited (as I can reassign it), but the asset seems messed up.

Does anyone has an idea of what can be the root cause of this ? Using `Xcode 9.3`.

Comment: @matt I don’t have any...

Comment: Hmm. Okay, let me suggest this: do things work any differently if you use the command line / SourceTree instead of Xcode's built-in git integration? I ask because I've never encountered this issue, but then, I _never_ use Xcode's built-in integration because it's so bad.

Comment: @matt Indeed, I've tried from command line and didn't notice this incorrect behavior. I also think that it comes from Xcode integration, but it never happened to me before today. I was suspecting maybe a bug related to Xcode 9(.3), or a misconfiguration in my project. Maybe I'll go with SourceTree from now if you recommend it and if it happens often...

Comment: I'll give this as a sort of guess-work answer just to complete the cycle...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a same issues whenever after git pull or clone.
I assume it is a Xcode bug vulnerable reading special characters other than Enligh characters.
**Mine fixed after changing image filename to english characters only without any special characters(other than English characters) included.**

Try fixing your asset file name to something else using just english characters.
I see your assets filename contains some special characters.

Comment: I had serious suspicion about special characters, you’ve confirmed it :) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the source control integration in Xcode since version 6 and today in Xcode 9.3 is more easy to use if you have nice configured, for example in my project there are three programmers and one use sourceTree, other use the command line and me xcode to send commits everyday and resolve conflicts with the files or merges, your issue is not related with the GUI or git operations.

You need to delete these files Unassigned, just click and press the button delete in your keyboard and remove all references so you can do clean and add again the file reference and assign, after you can do build and make a new commit using xcode and send the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Indeed, I'm also using Xcode integration since a while and never had any problem with it... This one is very strange. I know I can delete the Unassigned files but it is a repetitive task that I have to do after each project cloning, which can become embarassing...